# Simple Time Strategy in Pine

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to code a simple Trading view Strategy to back up a theory that the markets move a specific way on average at a certain time.

For example,

I want to short 100 at 9am UTC and close the position at 10am UTC everyday

I am not a coder but gave it a try..... It failed.

might anyone have an idea?

```
//@version=4

strategy("test")
if time > 32400
 strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, 100
if time > 36000
 strategy.cancel_all()
plot(strategy.equity)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this on EURUSD,1

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_value=100, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)
if hour == 9 and minute == 0
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
if hour == 10
    strategy.close_all()
```